# Потоки. События. Сокеты.

Tags: winapi, сокеты, потоки-данных

И снова они. Помогите разобраться. Фактически - нужен просто алгоритм, что куда. Практическая часть (примеры кода), конечно, не помешают. :) В общем, в который раз пишу эти строки:)

Есть игровой сервер. Программа с ним общается по **UDP**. Задача - при запуске программы каждую секунду отправлять на сервер команду и получать на неё ответ. Также чтобы была возможность отправки другой команды на сервер (пока без приема ответа сервера), не убивая первую.

Выбрал путь создания асинхронного сокета с потоками. Мой алгоритм примерно такой:
При запуске программы создается Событие (CreateEvent()). Дальше создается Поток #1(CreateThread()). В потоке создается сокет. Создает две структуры (т.к. UDP, для отправки сообщения на сервер и для бинда порта на локальном компе, на который придет пакет с сервером). И дальше каким-то макаром (каким?) ежесекундно отправляет и принимает информацию. При нажатии на Кнопку 1 создается Поток #2, в котором создается сокет с одной структурой (адресом до сервера), оттуда же сразу отправляется команда серверу и тут же убивает поток.

Собственно и всё. Вопрос - насколько правильно я описал алгоритм? Что добавить/удалить/поменять местами? И как это лучше реализовать в общем можно? Всё пытаюсь разобраться, но на разных форумах в примерах всегда всё по-разному и поэтому не понимаю пока. Может есть, что интересного по этому можно почитать?

Comment: А что мешает использовать один синхронный сокет?

Comment: Хм. А можно поточнее? Просто я думал, что для отправки просто сообщения нужно создать сокет, отправить, его убить, и, соответственно, что бы мониторить сервер каждую секунду с параллельной возможностью отправки "левой" команды, нужен еще один сокет...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сервер не обязательно проверять на доступность каждую секунду (мониторить). ЕСли сервер становится недоступен, то сокет автоматически закрывается, о чём можно уведомить пользователя. Все команды, в том числе и "левые" обрабатываются одним сокетом, при этом закрывать его следует когда, соединение с сервером уже не нужно (например закрытие приложения). Вобщем почитайте дополнительную инфу по этой теме

Comment: Неее, я его проверяю не на доступность, а основная задача, это получать с него данные каждую секунду. Спасибо за ответ, не знал, что нужен только один сокет. В таком случае другой вопрос, более профанский - как мне в одной функции создать сокет и структурам раздать IP и порты, и в другой функции, в команде sendto и/или recvto указать адрес уже созданного сокета?

Answer (score 1):

Для совмещения получения ответов сервера в темпе их поступления и отправки своих ежесекундных опросов используйте select() с таймаутом. Это в Вашем потоке 1.

Создайте сокет и структуру с адресом сервера, а также сделайте bind() в main() (при инициализации программы). Передайте их в создаваемый поток.

Нажатие Кнопки  обрабатывайте без всяких дополнительных потоков. Просто в main(), по этому событию делайте sendto() используя тот же сокет и адрес сервера, какой используете в потока с select().

Comment: Спасибо! Профанский вопрос такой же, как и выше - как передать сокет и структуру в другую функцию (точнее даже в другую cpp, потому что у меня с двух разных cpp-шек посылаться будут команды sendto())?

Comment: А что такое cpp-шка ?
Передать параметры в thread можно через последний параметр функции pthread_create(), а можно сделать их external.

Comment: *.cpp файл. Там я хочу как раз сделать создание сокета с привязкой к адресам и функции отправки/приема пакетов.

Comment: Просто вызывайте эти функции с параметрами. Или у Вас два main() т.е. параллельно работают два разных загрузочных модуля? В данном случае, мне кажется, это ни к чему.